# not able to update ubuntu or install apps in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager

When I try to update using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get error

```
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

And if I try to install any app the error I get is,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 is to be installed
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I already referred some solutions that were given for similar problems such as,

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
```

Not able to proceed with some solutions since update or installing is not possible.
What may be the reason for this problem and how can a resolve this?

Comment: `W: Failed to fetch ...` and `The following packages have unmet dependencies: ...` are actually two unrelated problems. The former is just a warning, so my suggestion relates to the latter: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Backup your source.list:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/sourcesBK.list
```

Download the "example repositories":

```
wget https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/sample/sources.list
```

and reemplace yours:

```
sudo cp sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And try to make an update:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Getting this error on running last command. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icedtea-7-jre-jamvm : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 is installed
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) but 7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: Try removing icedtea: sudo apt-get remove icedtea-7-jre-jamvm

I dont know really what its de problem with icedtea, buts apparenly have broken dependens. Maybe you have same ppa or source broken.